# how to get frame from video in iphone

Tags: iphone, video, frame

I want to fetch Frame from video and show it on the UIImageView. Please Help me how to fetch       frame from video and show it on the my UIImageview.

Comment: Where has the video come from? What format is it in? What have you already tried?

Comment: Nikhil Bansal I want to Key Frame  from video and show it on the UIImageview

Comment: @mattjgalloway i m fetchin video from iphone library in mp4 format and mov format i have tried 

+(UIImage *)fFirstVideoFrame:(NSString *)Url
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
             initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Url]];
    UIImage *img = [mp thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 
             timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    [mp stop];
    [mp release];
    return img;
}
But not able to find out keyframe please help me

Comment: @dheeru edit your question to add the code that you have posted in your comment.

Comment: Do a bit of research in SO and google. Lot of stuff on this subject exists. Then, ask a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i have solved the problem using this code

```
UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0
  timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame]; 

imageView.image = thumbnail;
```

Thanks
dheerendra singh

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
  CGRect rect = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame ;
```

it will return you frame of application screen area in points (i.e. entire screen minus status bar if visible)

if you ant to generate an image. You can also try AVAssetImageGenerator.

Comment: He means a frame of video, not a frame in the UIView sense.

Comment: now i have solve the problem
using this code

UIImage *thumbnail = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:0.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
mageView.image = thumbnail;